# How can I efficiently find the most important subset of a machine learning training set and rank the set elements by importance

Tags: machine-learning, clustering, optimization, cart

Suppose I cluster a set of records. I now wish to know which records in the set would maximise the disruption to the clusters if they were removed and the data reclustered.

I also require the same with decision trees. If I build a decision tree from a set of records, how can I establish the records to leave out to maximise the change in prediction over the entire set.

Obviously I want to minimise the number of records removed in both cases. So removing all the records is not a valid solution.

Comment: You need to define what constitutes "disruption" for your specific context. You will also need to define the number of data to remove, since you can always make it worse by removing one more & you don't want the answer to be 'all'.

Comment: I suspect the answer is a Pareto optimal frontier, which answers the question 'for each i < n how do I remove i records from the entire set of size n and remove the maximal amount of information encoded by the clusters assuming the number of clusters is unchanged'. With decision trees I'd be looking for something similar, e.g. if there were only two classes how would I locate the minimal set to remove from the training set for the new decision tree, in the optimal case,  to swap the predicted classifications.